# Debian unbootable for MBR and grub-efi

Tags: debian, grub2, kvm, uefi, mbr

I run Debian Jessie (amd64) on my host.
I use Debian Jessie (amd64) as guest (with qemu-kvm).

I run `kvm` as:

```
/usr/bin/kvm -monitor stdio \
             -smp 2 -soundhw ac97 -vga std \
             -enable-kvm -m 512 \
             -drive file=usb32g.qcow2,cache=writeback,aio=threads \
             -boot once=d,menu=off \
             -net nic,vlan=0,macaddr=00:5a:2f:09:1a:99 -net user,vlan=0 \
             -no-quit -name "deb-x64" \
             -bios /usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd
```

And when i start VM, efi-firmware reported:

```
Boot Failed. debian
```

As i can guess, efi-firmware can find partition with efi bootloader, but something went wrong. BTW, if i supply netinst iso-image, efi-firmware boot the debian-installer, i can accsess shell, chroot to system installed on `usb32g.qcow2`, reinstall `grub-efi` and run `update-grub`, but it has no effect.

The EFI-partition is located on primary MBR-partition with number 2 (i. e. `/dev/sda2`), and root file system is located on logical MBR-partition (i. e. `/dev/sda6`).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you had and for me the solution was, that there seems to be a [bug in VB](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14142), that you can't use SAS as controller. So I changed it to SATA and it works fine.